# Difficulty with SQL UNION involving queries with different number of columns, and other woes

Tags: sql, derby

I'm part of a Toastmasters club, and just got put in charge of scheduling which members serve which roles in the weekly meetings.  I'm writing a small app to help manage this, with the idea that a database can help me determine fairly which member is most overdue to serve in each role.

To simplify matters, let's say that my database has two tables... `MEMBER` and `ROLE_PERFORMED`:

```
MEMBER
------
ID int
NAME varchar


ROLE_PERFORMED
--------------
MEMBER_ID int   (half of primary key, and also foreign key)
DATE date   (other half of primary key)
ROLE int   (0-11, mapped to an enumeration at the application layer)
```

My goal is to write a SQL query for each role type, which will give me:

- `MEMBER.NAME`, for all rows in the `MEMBER` table
- A second column, containing the *most recent* `ROLE_PERFORMED.DATE` value matching that member and role... or else a `NULL` (or some other placeholder) if the member has *never* served in that role

I could then order by the date/placeholder column, and assign roles in order of who has gone the longest time without performing that role.  Something like this:

```
ROLE     NAME    MOST_RECENTLY_PERFORMED
--------------------------------
1        John    <null>
1        Joe     2010-02-25
1        Bob     2010-09-14
```

The approach I'm currently taking is to try a `UNION`... between one `SELECT` that grabs those members who have performed the role, and a second SELECT grabbing members who have never performed the role.  Something like this:

```
SELECT m.name, r.date FROM member m, role_performed r WHERE m.id = r.member_id and r.role = 1
UNION
SELECT m.name, (NULL?????) FROM member m, role_performed r WHERE (?????)
```

There are three problems with this, however, for which I'm hoping someone may have solutions:

- The first `SELECT` grabs *all* dates for which the member performed the role, not just the most recent.
- The second `SELECT` causes the `UNION` to fail, because I can't find an acceptable placeholder value to use for the second date column... and `UNION`'s require each query to return the same number of columns.
- The second `WHERE` clause is simply beyond my limited SQL skills.  How do you find all `MEMBER` rows, which do *not* have a `ROLE_PERFORMED` rows matching that member and that role?  Bear in mind that there *can* still be `ROLE_PERFORMED` rows matching that member and some *other* role.

Like I said, I'm not the greatest SQL guru in the world... so I would welcome altogether different approaches if I'm making this more complicated than it needs to be.  Heck, I would welcome a better question title to help meaningfully present what I'm asking!  Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of these queries come really close to everything I need, and I really appreciate everyone who responded.  However, ultimately I ended up accomplishing everything I needed with some logic up in the application layer.  One of these SQL queries might get the job done on a more complete database platform, but perhaps the embedded Derby database just doesn't support enough of the standard.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
SELECT member.name , role_performed.date  FROM member
LEFT JOIN role_performed on role_perfomed.member_id = member.id
ORDER BY role_performed.date
```

Comment: That's half of it.  But I also need all "members" which do NOT have a "role_performed" row matching that member ID and role ID combo (i.e. the members who have never performed that role at all).  This INNER JOIN query above is going to return only those members who do have a match.

Comment: try LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN

Comment: Here's the error message I get when trying this.  It makes no sense to me, because 'ROLE_PERFOMED.MEMBER_ID' very much IS a valid column in that table:          "Column 'ROLE_PERFOMED.MEMBER_ID' is either not in any table in the FROM list or appears within a join specification and is outside the scope of the join specification or appears in a HAVING clause and is not in the GROUP BY list. If this is a CREATE or ALTER TABLE  statement then 'ROLE_PERFOMED.MEMBER_ID' is not a column in the target table."

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you will have to use CROSS JOIN like this:

SELECT 
    R.RoleId,
    Max(R.Date),
    M.Name
FROM
    Member M
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT
    R1.RoleId,
    R1.MemberId,
    R.Date
FROM
    Role_Performed R
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
(
SELECT
    R2.RoleId,
    R1.MemberId,
    R2.Date
FROM
        Role_Performed R1
**CROSS JOIN**  Role_Performed R2
) R1 ON R1.Date = R.Date AND R1.MemberId = R.MemberId
) 
R ON M.MemberId = R.MemberId
GROUP BY R.RoleId, M.Name
ORDER BY
    R.RoleId
GO

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT m.Name, oj.RoleID, MAX(r.Date)
FROM member m JOIN
    (
        SELECT m.MemberID, ar.RoleID
        FROM member m, (SELECT DISTINCT RoleID FROM role_performed) ar
    ) oj ON m.MemberID = oj.MemberID
    LEFT JOIN role_performed r ON r.MemberID = oj.MemberID AND r.RoleID = oj.RoleID
GROUP BY m.MemberID, r.RoleID
```

Answer (score -2):

I would do it like this hope this helps

SELECT member.name , 
       Max(role_performed.date)
FROM member 
LEFT JOIN role_performed on role_perfomed.member_id = member.id 
GROUP BY ROLE,member.name 
ORDER BY ROLE,member.name